# site to site VPN

Tags: pfsense, sonicwall, site-to-site-vpn

The problem i am facing is establishment of a site to site VPN in between pfSense( version 2.0.1) and SonicWall Pro2040 Enhanced ( Firmware Version: SonicOS Enhanced 4.2.1.4-7e) .
All of the configuration is done properly , still i got the following error in sonicwall -

"Payload processing failed "

Phase 1 and 2 passes properly but problem with "Payload processing" i found that it could be for shared key mismatch but I double check , no mismatch with shared key in both firewall .
It also shows in sonicwall that tunnel is active

The log from pfSense is below -

Comment: You haven't posted your log

Answer (score 3):

Here is the setting for my sonicwall and pfsense:

General tab on Sonicwall:

```
Authentication Method: IKE using Pre shared Secret

Name:  pfSense Site-to-Site PN

IPsec Primary Gateway Name or Address: 1.1.1.1 | IP for pfSense

IPsec Secondary Gateway Name or Address: 0.0.0.0

Shared Secret: Shared secret for this connection

Local IKE ID:  2.2.2.2 | Select ‘IP Address’ from the drop down menu and then type WAN IP of Sonicwall



Network tab on Sonicwall:

Local Networks

Choose local network from list: 192.168.21.0 | Create an address object for the network or you can use the built in one ‘LAN Subnets’

Destination Networks

Choose destination network from list: 192.168.65.0 | Create an address object for the remote LAN network



Proposals Tab:

IKE (Phase 1) Proposal

By default pfSense supports ‘Main Mode’ and ‘Aggressive’.

Exchange: Aggressive

DH Group: Group 2

Encryption: 3DES

Authentication: SHA1

Life Time (seconds): 28800

Ipsec (Phase 2) Proposal

Protocol: ESP

Encryption: 3DES

Authentication: SHA1

Enable Perfect Forward Secrecy: Checked

Life Time: 86400



Advanced Tab:

Check ‘Enable Keep Alive’
```

Corresponding pfSense Settings:

```
Phase 1:

Authentication method: Mutual PSK

Negotiation Mode: Aggressive

My identifier: 1.1.1.1 (IP Address of pfSense WAN)

Peer identifier: 2.2.2.2 (IP Address of Sonicwall)

Pre Shared Key: Your pre share key

Policy Generation: Default

Proposal Checking: Obey

Encryption Algorithm: 3DES

Hash algorithm: SHA1

DH key group: 2

Lifetime: 28800



Advanced options

Nat Traversal: Enable

Dead Peer Detection: Check Enable DPD



Phase 2:

Mode: Tunnel

Local Network: 192.168.65.0/24

Remote Network: 192.168.21.0/24

Protocol: ESP

Encryption algorithms: 3DES

Hash algorithms: SHA1

PFS key group: 2

Lifetime: 84600
```

Please see my [article](http://zee.linxsol.com/system-administration/pfsense-2-site-to-site-vpn-with-dell-sonicwall-nsa-3500.html) how to configure sonicwall with pfsense.